# Two values either way round in two fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a table called 'friends', this contains the columns `person1` and `person2`.
I'm using PHP to check if a user is friends with a person. I want to do a query which will see if:

- `person1` is Bob and `person2` is Jim
- `person1` is Jim and `person2` is Bob

In other words, I want to check if they're both present in the same row. Not Jim with someone else and not Bob with someone else.
It must be Bob and Jim together in the same row. What query would I use to get the row? I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
SELECT person1, person2 FROM friends WHERE (person1=Jim AND person2=Bob) OR (person1=Bob AND person2=Jim)
```

Of course this wouldn't work in SQL, but I'm looking for something along these lines. I don't want friendship duplicates in the table.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Other than your strings not being in quotes, why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Doh! I didn't try it, I thought I was just writing pseudocode, no idea MySQL could do that; Thanks, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To eliminate duplicates (the row with Jim/Bob and the 'duplicate' with Bob/Jim), you'll need to add a case statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN person1 = 'Jim' 
     THEN person1 
     ELSE person2 END AS person1Derivation,
CASE WHEN person2 = 'Bob'
     THEN person2
     ELSE person1 END AS person2Derivation
FROM friends
WHERE (person1 = 'Jim' and person2 = 'Bob') or (person1 = 'Bob' and person2 = 'Jim')
```